# “.push is not a function” error while inserting key-value to an array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, dictionary, angularjs-scope

I’m trying push `ItemId(as a key)` and `PartNO(value)` to an array dynamically based on `Noof ItemPartDtls` using a `for` loop so that I can again fetch those `PartNO`s using `ItemID` in the `for` loop when required.

But I got the error message:

> `TypeError: NoofParts.push is not a function`

while pushing.

```js
var NoofParts = []; // initialized globally

if ($scope.ItemPartDtls.length > 0) {    
    for (let e = 0; e <= $scope.ItemPartDtls.length - 1; e++) {
        // NoofParts.push({ "ItemID": $scope.ItemsInfo[d].ITEM_ID, "PartNO":  $scope.ItemPartDtls[e].PART_NO });
        NoofParts.push({ ItemID: $scope.ItemsInfo[d].ITEM_ID, PartNO: $scope.ItemPartDtls[e].PART_NO});
        // error here: TypeError: NoofParts.push is not a function
    }
}

...

function GetPartdtls(ItmId){
    for(i = 0; i < NoofParts.length; i++){
        if(NoofParts[i].ItemID == ItmId) {
            console.log("ItemID:- " + NoofParts[i].ItemID + " PartNO:- "  + NoofParts[i].PartNO);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can u do console.log(typeof NoofParts) before NoofParts.push? I doubt it is changed somewhere else in ur code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this way

```
 var NoofParts =  []; // initialized globally

if ($scope.ItemPartDtls.length > 0) {    
   for (let e = 0; e <= $scope.ItemPartDtls.length - 1; e++) {
       // NoofParts.push({ "ItemID": $scope.ItemsInfo    [d].ITEM_ID, "PartNO":  $scope.ItemPartDtls[e].PART_NO});
        let newArr = { 
                       ItemID: $scope.ItemsInfo[e].ITEM_ID, //here your typo error
                       PartNO: $scope.ItemPartDtls[e].PART_NO
                      }
        NoofParts.push(newArr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should ideally work, but to double proof, try the below method

```
(function() {

  let NoofParts = []; // initialized globally

  if ($scope.ItemPartDtls.length > 0) {
    for (let e = 0; e <= $scope.ItemPartDtls.length - 1; e++) {
      if (!Array.isArray(NoofParts)) {
        NoofParts = [];
      }
      NoofParts.push({
        ItemID: $scope.ItemsInfo[d].ITEM_ID,
        PartNO: $scope.ItemPartDtls[e].PART_NO
      }); // error here: TypeError: NoofParts.push is not a function
    }
  }

})();
```